# How to handle varying chip voltages on an I2C line?

Tags: integrated-circuit, i2c, digital-communications, serial-bus

I am working on a design where I have various chips that operate at different voltages that I am trying to put on one I2C bus. Normally I'd just pick different chips that accomplish the same goal with the same operating voltage but that is not possible here. The setup is essentially seen below. There is another 2 5V ICs, another 3.3V IC, and another 1.8V IC but I think that is irrelevant to the fundamental issue.

The attached picture has the setup. Do I need to level shift the I2C data and clock somehow? If so, how can I go about doing this? What level should the pull up resistor go to? In general, what is the best way to handle this?

[image]

Comment: First of all you should say what chips those are. Some 5V chips may be compatible with a 3.3V bus, and some 1.8V chips may be compatible with a 3.3V bus. Have you checked all the requirements for each chip?

Comment: It depends on MCU also. Many new MCUs support separate powers for GPIOs and someitmes it is easier to split bus to two buses.

Answer (score 2):

If the chips don't share a common single bus voltage they are all compatible with, you can have a single bus with multiple segments, each running on different voltage.

Voltage level translation ICs exist for I2C. Also many kind of I2C muxes and switch ICs can be used to divide the bus into multiple segments, each with their own voltage level.

Answer (score 1):

> The attached picture has the setup. Do I need to level shift the I2C
> data and clock somehow?

Yes, you need to level shift. Make sure the 1.8 device can't be run at 3.3V or is 3.3V tolerant. Look for bi-directional level shifters

Ti makes a few:
TXS0102
TCA9517ADGKR

Watch out for power sequencing on these devices.

Comment: I do not recommend using either of the chips you mention, if you simply want to level shift. It takes great care to get those bus repeaters with rise time accelerators working, and depending on chip, they may have limitations how to connect a multitude of them, if even possible. My advice is, don't use a repeater unless you need a repeater. If you just need level shifting, use simpler chips that are easier to work with.

Comment: What chip would that be? Most of the ones I've seen use the one-shot with pull up scheme even from different manufacturers

Comment: For example just two FETs, or PCA9306 if you have to have a chip.